# How can this jquery be implemented in meteor helpers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, meteor

Since meteor jquery syntax is different how can this be implemented?

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'mouseup body': function (e){
   var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

   if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
   {
       container.hide();
   }
}
```